# Displaying Month and Days inside html table using JavaScript in blade template

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

**Question: 1.)** how do i remove this 1901 00:00:00 GMT+0655 (Singapore Standard Time) inside my date, i want the circled item only to show.[image]

**Question: 2.)** how can i display those days into my table using [td or th]

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  Attendance(1, 2012);function Attendance(month, year) {
 var date = new Date(month,1);
 var days = [];
 while (date.getMonth() === month) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    days.push(new Date(date));  
 }
 return days;}
```

Comment: Can you post the sample data not in a image format

Comment: sorry i'm newbie whatis moment and where to learn it?

Comment: go to their official website https://momentjs.com/

Comment: What sample post u asking?

Comment: that was just a suggestion but if you don't want to use that, you simply use to parse your data

Comment: You data sample which is in image format

Comment: yeah it is an image and my javascript code is below

Comment: Can you post your real data not in an image format

Comment: how do i post the data? that image is the result from my blade view..inside the div element

Comment: Convert each date object to string and parse the string

Comment: @ charlietfl can show me example if u don't mind

Comment: If that is in blade template then use php date formatting...easily researched

Comment: @ charlietfl  thank you u gave me idea haha id rather use php on this to display it inside my table

Comment: @Grace I have included the running code snippet for your reference

Comment: What exactly is this `Attendance` function intended to do? It is giving you dates from February of the year 1901: is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so to answer your question I have prepared a sample input from your image data. For this problem I have taken this as a data. As you mentioned in your comment the data is in you div element.

In the snippet below you will get the days of the week according to local time where 0 represents Sunday

Refer this doc for more [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

```js
    var data = document.getElementById("date");
    var value = data.innerHTML; //here you will get your data by comma seperated
    var date = value.split(","); //split the data using ,
    //loop through the array to find out the days
    for(var i= 0;i<date.length;i++){
        var day = new Date(date[i]).getDay();
        if(day == 0){
          console.log("Sunday")
        }
        if(day == 1){
          console.log("Monday")
        }
        if(day == 2){
          console.log("Tuesday")
        }
        if(day == 3){
          console.log("Wednesday")
        }
        if(day == 4){
          console.log("Thursday")
        }
        if(day == 5){
          console.log("Friday")
        }
        if(day == 6){
          console.log("Saturday")
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div id = "date">
      Sat Feb 02 1901 00:00:00:00 GMT+0655(Singapore), Sun Feb 03 1901 00:00:00:00 GMT+0655(Singapore), Mon Feb 04 1901 00:00:00:00 GMT+0655(Singapore)
    </div>
```